# Why does the jquery selector ("id,id") selects all elements with duplicate IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I came across some **year old** code written by a good developer (yes, I knew him personally) to access all elements having the same id.

```
$("#choice,#choice")
```

It returns all elements having the id. But if we use the below

```
$("#choice")
```

It returns only the first match, as expected.

After searching for some time, I'm unable to figure out any official links pointing to his technique, as to how it selected all elements with duplicate id.

Can anyone please explain how is this working ?

**UPDATE**

Please see the question is not about what alternative to use. I'm aware of classSelectors and attributeSelectors and know having duplicate IDs is not recommended, but sometimes you just have to live with years old code the way it is (if you know what I mean).

http://jsbin.com/zodeyexigo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document). use class instead of id

Comment: _"all elements having the same id"_ Same id as what?

Comment: How many is it actually returning, two items back? i would have throught that the usage of the #choice,#choice, is like doing a similar selection if you wanted to get back 2 different inputs into an array collection, say it maybe #choice,#choice2. If its not returning 2 items back then im clearly completely wrong.

Comment: @Arvind: ___Don't ever___ use an attribute selector for `id`. Use `$("#choice")` instead.

Comment: How many elements you have in your DOM containing id `#choice`?

Comment: Of course, we can resort to using classes or attribute-selector, but my question is about `how is it working` ? It's returning all elements having `id=choice` which is 5 in my case.

Comment: "written by a good developer" but not following the proper use for `DOM` attribute such as `id`.

Comment: probably the DOM is written by someone else long time ago and he had to figure out a way to select all elements without disturbing anything else.

Comment: here is a fiddle demo- he's asking- http://jsfiddle.net/ccunbs3s/

Comment: -1 This shows lack of research. The first one is quickly passed to `document.getElementById()`, which returns only 1 element. The selector `#id,#id` is more complex and is passed to Sizzle for processing.

Answer (score 11):

If you look at the code of [sizzle.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/external/sizzle/dist/sizzle.js) that jQuery uses for selecting elements based on selector you will understand why this happens. It uses following regex to match simple ID, TAG or class selector:

```
// Easily-parseable/retrievable ID or TAG or CLASS selectors
rquickExpr = /^(?:#([\w-]+)|(\w+)|\.([\w-]+))$/,
```

but as the selector in question is `$("#ID,#ID")` it does not match with the selector and uses `querySelectorAll` (line no 270 in ref link), which replaces selector to `"[id='" + nid + "'] "` (line no 297 in ref link) which selects all the elements with matching ID.

However, I agree with the other people in this thread, that it is not good idea to have same ID for multiple elements.

Comment: You forgot to mention that a selector like `#id` is passed to `document.getelementById()`.

Answer (score 3):

Having 2 elements with the same ID is not valid html according to the W3C specification.

When your CSS selector only has an ID selector (and is not used on a specific context), jQuery uses the native document.getElementById method, which returns only the first element with that ID.

However, in the other two instances, jQuery relies on the Sizzle selector engine (or querySelectorAll, if available), which apparently selects both elements. Results may vary on a per browser basis.

However, you should never have two elements on the same page with the same ID. If you need it for your CSS, use a class instead.

If you absolutely must select by duplicate ID, use an attribute selector:

```
$('[id="a"]');
```

Take a look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P2j3f/2/

Note: if possible, you should qualify that selector with a tag selector, like this:

```
$('span[id="a"]');
```

Answer (score -1):

So in JS Fiddle i have shown an example of what jQuery is doing.

https://jsfiddle.net/akp3a7La/

When you have a

```
$('#choice,#choice');
```

It is actually getting all the instances of the objects #choice twice, and then filtering out any duplicates.

in my example i show you how it does that also when you have something like this

```
$("#choice,li");
```

Where

items are actually your #choice items.

In the Jquery Documentation
https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

it talks about multiple Selectors, which is what i think is happening here, your developer friend is selecting the same ID twice, and it would be returning it twice. as you can only have one input with the same ID once on a page (good html syntax)

Comment: nope, it returns all elements (more than two) having the same id.

Comment: On this page, `$("#notify-container,#notify-container")` is _only_ returning a single element for me.

Comment: @coding_idiot: It might help if we knew what HTML you are working with.

Comment: Silly question, why is their multiple containers on a page with an id that is the same, if it was for styling you would use a class attribute, $(".choice") or if you had the options with the same name attribute you would use something like $('[name=choice]'). BUT your question asked what the dual selector is, and it is called a multiple selector.

Answer (score -1):

Having duplicated id on the page making your html not valid . ID is **unique** identifier for one element on the page ([spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute)). Using classes, that are classify similar elements that's your case and `$('.choice')` will return set of elements

Comment: please see the updated question, I'm aware of how to make it better, but want to know why or better put "HOW" is it working in the first place.